# Losing file content in Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

This is a very strange phenomenon.
My app uses the Android Google Drive SDK to store two data files for every user.
These files are in the app folder. To get a connection to the Google service, I use :

```
PlusOptions plusOptions = new Plus.PlusOptions.Builder()
            .addActivityTypes("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity").build();
mGoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Plus.API, plusOptions).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

I am able to create these files and write them.
But from time to time, the two files disappear, and their content is lost.
The logcat stream contains messages like these:

```
05-16 10:15:18.316: W/GLSUser(829): [apk][apk] Permission for debut.kholle to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me will be managed remotely.
05-16 10:15:18.416: I/qtaguid(14877): Failed write_ctrl(u 56) res=-1 errno=22
05-16 10:15:18.416: I/qtaguid(14877): Untagging socket 56 failed errno=-22
05-16 10:15:18.416: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(14877): untagSocket(56) failed with errno -22
05-16 10:15:18.416: I/imp(14877): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
05-16 10:15:18.416: I/imp(14877): Retrying request
05-16 10:15:18.436: W/GLSUser(829): [apk][apk] Permission for debut.kholle to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me will be managed remotely.
05-16 10:15:18.516: W/GLSUser(829): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-16 10:15:18.546: I/qtaguid(21108): Failed write_ctrl(u 85) res=-1 errno=22
05-16 10:15:18.546: I/qtaguid(21108): Untagging socket 85 failed errno=-22
05-16 10:15:18.546: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(21108): untagSocket(85) failed with errno -22
05-16 10:15:18.546: I/imp(21108): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
05-16 10:15:18.546: I/imp(21108): Retrying request
05-16 10:15:19.576: E/SyncSchedulerImpl(14877): Ignoring sync request:  rate limited (on connection limit)
```

**Edit:**

Here is my code to read a file containing application data. This code is included in the activity `onCreate` procedure:

```
monGoogleApiLire = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Filter titreFilter = Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, NOM_FICHIER_PLANNING);
                    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(titreFilter).build();
                    Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(monGoogleApiLire).queryChildren(monGoogleApiLire, query)
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
                                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        // showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    MetadataBuffer meta = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                                    if (meta.getCount() != 0) {
                                        int nb = meta.getCount();
                                        DriveId idc = null;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
                                            idc = meta.get(i).getDriveId();
                                        }
                                        DriveFile fichier = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(monGoogleApiLire, idc);
                                        fichier.openContents(monGoogleApiLire, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
                                                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                                            // display an error saying file can't be opened
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                        // Contents object contains pointers
                                                        // to the actual byte stream
                                                        Contents contents = result.getContents();
                                                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                                                new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                                                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                                        String line;
                                                        try {
                                                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                                                builder.append(line);
                                                            }
                                                            String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                                                            reader.close();

                                                            }

                                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                        contents.close();
                                                        // fichier.commitAndCloseContents(gapi, contents);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        monPlanning = new ArrayList<DonneesPlanning>();
                                        afficherPlanning();
                                        if (monPlanning != null && mesCours != null && mesLieux != null) {
                                            ActiviteKholle.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                                            monGoogleApiLire.disconnect();
                                        }
                                        // monGoogleApiLire.disconnect();
                                    }
                                    meta.close();
                                }

                            });
                    titreFilter = Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, NOM_FICHIER_COURS);
                    query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(titreFilter).build();
                    Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(monGoogleApiLire).queryChildren(monGoogleApiLire, query)
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
                                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        // showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    MetadataBuffer meta = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                                    if (meta.getCount() != 0) {
                                        int nb = meta.getCount();
                                        DriveId idc = null;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
                                            idc = meta.get(i).getDriveId();
                                        }
                                        DriveFile fichier = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(monGoogleApiLire, idc);
                                        fichier.openContents(monGoogleApiLire, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
                                                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                                            // display an error saying file can't be opened
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                        // Contents object contains pointers
                                                        // to the actual byte stream
                                                        Contents contents = result.getContents();
                                                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                                                new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                                                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                                        String line;
                                                        try {
                                                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                                                builder.append(line);
                                                            }
                                                            String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                                                            reader.close();

                                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                        contents.close();
                                                        // fichier.commitAndCloseContents(gapi, contents);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        mesCours = new ArrayList<DonneesCours>();
                                        if (monPlanning != null && mesCours != null && mesLieux != null) {
                                            ActiviteKholle.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                                            monGoogleApiLire.disconnect();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    meta.close();
                                }

                            });
                    titreFilter = Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, NOM_FICHIER_LIEUX);
                    query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(titreFilter).build();
                    Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(monGoogleApiLire).queryChildren(monGoogleApiLire, query)
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
                                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        // showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    MetadataBuffer meta = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                                    if (meta.getCount() != 0) {
                                        int nb = meta.getCount();
                                        DriveId idc = null;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
                                            idc = meta.get(i).getDriveId();
                                        }
                                        DriveFile fichier = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(monGoogleApiLire, idc);
                                        fichier.openContents(monGoogleApiLire, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
                                                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                                            // display an error saying file can't be opened
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                        // Contents object contains pointers
                                                        // to the actual byte stream
                                                        Contents contents = result.getContents();
                                                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                                                new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                                                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                                        String line;
                                                        try {
                                                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                                                builder.append(line);
                                                            }
                                                            String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                                                            reader.close();

                                                            if (monPlanning != null && mesCours != null
                                                                    && mesLieux != null) {
                                                                ActiviteKholle.this
                                                                        .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                                                                monGoogleApiLire.disconnect();
                                                            }
                                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                        contents.close();
                                                        // fichier.commitAndCloseContents(gapi, contents);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        mesLieux = new ArrayList<DonneesLieu>();
                                        if (monPlanning != null && mesCours != null && mesLieux != null) {
                                            ActiviteKholle.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                                            monGoogleApiLire.disconnect();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    meta.close();
                                }

                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }).build();


monGoogleApiLire.connect();
```

Is there an explanation for this ?

P.S. : After a lot of trials and test, I am now sure that the field "monGoogleApi" is connected when I test the file existence. When I use "queryChildren" to search for the file by name and mime type, on the line of code :

```
if (meta.getCount() != 0) {
...
}
```

During 15 minutes, meta.getCount is equal to 1, after 15 minutes, meta.getCount equals 0.

Comment: Exactly how are you attempting to get these files and view the contents?  What makes you think they disappeared?

Comment: I added my code to read a data file. I am able to use the app with its data during about 15 minutes, and then, the data doesn't come back ...

Comment: Are you making modifications to the data ever?  You are saying if you call that same method 15 minutes later it has different content, even though you didn't make any changes?  Do you have the same app installed anywhere else? A web version?

Comment: Yes, the app files contain data in JSON format. So when the user add objects in the app, I simply rewrite all data content and close the file. If I launch again the app after roughly 15 minutes, the files seam to be empty. I test my app on different devices, every device has a different Google user (so a different drive). No web version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the connection status of "monGoogleApi" ?

This connection may have a session timeout.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#isConnected%28%29)

Comment: In fact, I use several GoogleApiClient variables : the first one exactly as described in the official documentation (inside activity callbacks) to display the user name and photo, the second one to read files content, the third one to write files content. For the 2nd and 3rd, I use connect and then google drive sdk api calls in the connection callbacks. So I think, I cannot call google drive api calls if I am not connected.

Comment: Indeed you can't call the api if you're not connected and yes the callback wouldn't be called if you weren't connected. However I assumed that "monGoogleApi" is stored as a field in your class and when you call "readDataFile()" its uses this field. Thus the field might not be null but its internal connection may be disconnected.

IMHO you should check the connection before and tell us if this solved you problem :)

Comment: I changed my code since I asked this question on Stackoverflow. You can find it in the question now. As you can see, I call drive sdk calls inside the connection callbacks. This code works perfectly during a while, and after about 15 minutes, files content have disappeared when I launch the app again.